# TypeScript: Generic types for functions treat parameters as "any" despite declaring them otherwise

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, function-parameter

Using TypeScript 4.4.3, I want to be able to explicitly type function parameters to a function that returns a generic. TypeScript is ignoring the types for the parameters to functions that use generics treating them as `any`.

The following is a contrived example (not a very useful function) that will show a warning on the input parameter saying it's of type "any" if it's pasted into the TS Playground...

```js
type GenericResult = <T>(input: number) => T
export const returnWhatever: GenericResult = <T>(input) => <T> input
```

Is the parameter's type defined in the first line supposed to be ignored?

My actual use-case looks like this...

```js
import type { QueryResult } from 'pg'
import pg from 'pg'

const pgNativePool = new pg.native.Pool({
  max: 10,
  connectionString: import.meta.env.VITE_DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})

type AcceptableParams = number | string | boolean

type PostgresQueryResult = (sql: string, params?: AcceptableParams[]) => Promise<QueryResult<any>>
const query: PostgresQueryResult = (sql, params?) => pgNativePool.query(sql, params)

type GetOneResult = <T>(sql: string, id: number | string) => Promise<T>
const getOne: GetOneResult = async <T>(sql, id) => {
  const { rows } = await query(sql, [id])
  return <T> rows[0]
}

const user = await getOne<User>('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1;', 33)
// returns a User
```

In this example above, the sql parameter must always be a string and the id can be a number or a string.

While the type of the return value for the function is determined where the function is called, it still seemed like a good idea to be able to type the parameters to that function since that part is known.

Possible?

Comment: not 100% sure but I don't think the type of `returnWhatever` has any bearing on the type of the lambda function that you're assigning to it, at least necessarily. the types on `input => input` are open enough that it can be massaged to fit `NonGenericResult` but since `GenericResult` has a `T` it's more complex and less 'open'. I think there's a better way to explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation from Microsoft is to explicitly type the parameters in the generic function's definition as I have done below with the getOne function below. This doesn't "feel" right because I'm defining the parameter types twice but whatever...

```js
import type { QueryResult } from 'pg'
import pg from 'pg'

const pgNativePool = new pg.native.Pool({
  max: 10,
  connectionString: import.meta.env.VITE_DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})

type AcceptableParams = number | string | boolean

type PostgresQueryResult = (sql: string, params?: AcceptableParams[]) => Promise<QueryResult<any>>
const query: PostgresQueryResult = (sql, params?) => pgNativePool.query(sql, params)

type GetOneResult = <T>(sql: string, id: number | string) => Promise<T>
const getOne: GetOneResult = async <T>(sql: string, id: number | string) => {
  const { rows } = await query(sql, [id])
  return <T> rows[0]
}

const user = await getOne<User>('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1;', 33)
// returns a User
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated example based on conversation

```
type GenericResult = <T = number>(input: T) => T;
export const returnWhatever: GenericResult = (input) => input;

returnWhatever<string>("1");
returnWhatever(1);
returnWhatever<number>("1"); // will error
```

Typescript is getting confused because it thinks you're overriding the types for the function args. I think you did this because you want to re-specify the generic but you do not have to do this as you have typed this on the type for the arrow function. This should be sufficient:

```
type GetManyResults = <T>(sql: string) => Promise<{ body: T[]; }>
export const getMany: GetManyResults = async (sql) => {
  const { rows } = await query(sql)
  return {
    body: rows
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot_2]

Comment: That's how I originally had the function (no type on sql) but if I remove it and hover over getMany's sql param, it says "any" rather than "string". That doesn't happen for the functions that do not return a generic. Seems like a bug.

Comment: @nstuyvesant check the screenshot I've added, do you have the files available to download as a minimal example? Use codesandbox? :)

Comment: Good point - I've updated my example to be 100% standalone so it's easier to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @nstuyvesant your example has an error, you can't type the body as returning something generic and then return input for body as that has been typed with number. Can you upload a screenshot of the exact error you're facing so I can see what TSC is saying?

Comment: Updated the example to remove extraneous elements and included a screenshot from VS Code.

Comment: @nstuyvesant do you have a screenshot of the original issue so I can see "any" error

Comment: Hi @Win - Yes - I added the screenshot to my original post above. If you copy/paste the example into VS Code on your computer, I'm confident it will reproduce.

Comment: @nstuyvesant The example above is wrong as the the returnwhatever method is returning input which has a type of number but the type uses the generic as the return type, therefore that example will error indefinitely.

Comment: This is a simplified example of what is really happening, but I would expect `returnWhatever<number>(1)` to return a number with the value of 1.

Comment: The correct typing for the above code is in the snippet but I still don't think it's a solution to your original problem.

Comment: Just added the code playground. Please check it out. It underlines the input parameter of the second function and says it has the type of "any" (even there).

Comment: @nstuyvesant you're still trying to override the args types, this will never work.

Comment: Where am I doing that in these two lines of code... type GenericResult = <T>(input: number) => T
export const returnWhatever: GenericResult = <T>(input) =>  <T> input

Comment: @nstuyvesant As soon as you prefix the args with the generic, it will ignore the args from `GenericResult` you shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: That describes the behavior I'm seeing (function with function type like GenericResult that includes a generic ignores the types for the parameters). I guess I'm not understanding why TypeScript should ignore the parameter types for a function that returns a generic. My actual use-case is to pass in a number of typed parameters (like a sql string) that perform a query and return an array of type <T> according to what was called.

Comment: @nstuyvesant I think you're misunderstanding the "type inference" that occurs here. I don't know the correct terminology or I'd post an answer. The lambda `input => input` would implicitly be type `any => any`, but is narrowed to `number => number` by the assignment. I don't know what this narrowing is called or I'd point you toward a documentation source. The narrowing on `GenericResult` is not able to happen due to the generic (in the lambda). Your lambda is of type `<T>(any) => T` and can't be narrowed through assignment. It's possible because the two `T`s cannot be merged, but not sure.